# Insert values from one uitableview to multiple uitableviews?

Tags: sqlite, uitableview, ios4, uisegmentedcontrol

HI,
    I have inserted the values from sqlite table to uitableView.But now I have the segmentedControl in other view.As i click on first tab of segmentedControl I need to get half values of uitableview to the uitableview attached to sementedControl.And when I click on Other tab I neeed to get other half values from uitableview to the another UITableview Atttached to segmented control.

thank u

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833238/uisegmentedcontrol-how-to-toggle-between-2-uitableviews) might help. Otherwise [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050381/how-does-one-design-the-datasource-for-a-uitableview-in-order-to-sort-with-a-uise).

Sounds like you need 2 `NSArray` objects holding your 2 set of values from your sqlite data. Then when you select from the `UISegmentedControl`, point to the correct set of data and call `[tableview reloadData]` say.